# Javascript MQTT Broker Messages To Topic Only Appear When Sent Locally

Tags: javascript, websocket, mqtt, mosquitto, paho

I have an MQTT connection set up with port 8081 (websockets). The on message receive callback does not display any messages other than the 'test' message I send at the start of my script:

```
function onConnect() {
  // Once a connection has been made, make a subscription and send a message.
  console.log("onConnect");
  mqtt.subscribe("drivingStatus");
  message = new Paho.Message("test");
  message.destinationName = "drivingStatus";
  mqtt.send(message);
}
```

This message 'test' appears in the onMessagedArrived Function:

```
function onMessageArrived(message) {
  console.log(message.payloadString)
  // console.log("onMessageArrived:"+message.payloadString);
}
```

However, when a message is posted to the topic 'drivingStatus' from a python script (targetting port 1883) the message does not appear in the console. Despite the message appearing on the MQTT brokers console.

**How can Javascript Paho MQTT connections sync with the MQTT broker correctly?**

The expected output is for all messages to be displayed in the console (as are currently seen when subscribing via terminal after entering the command `mosquitto_sub -d -t drivingStatus`)

The entire code is:

```
var mqtt
var reconnectTimeout = 2000
var host = "x"
var port = 8081


var r = Math.random().toString(36).substring(7);
        var client = "hmack00" + r 
function onConnect() {
  // Once a connection has been made, make a subscription and send a message.
  console.log("onConnect");
  mqtt.subscribe("drivingStatus");
  message = new Paho.Message("test");
  message.destinationName = "drivingStatus";
  mqtt.send(message);
}

function onFailure(message) {
  console.log("Connection Attempt to Host "+host+"Failed");
  setTimeout(MQTTconnect, reconnectTimeout);
}

function onMessageArrived(message) {
  console.log(message.payloadString)
  // console.log("onMessageArrived:"+message.payloadString);
}

mqtt = new Paho.Client(host, port, client);
console.log("connecting to " + host)
var options = {
  timeout: 3,
  onSuccess: onConnect,
  onFailure: onFailure,
};

mqtt.onMessageArrived = onMessageArrived;
mqtt.connect(options);
```

Comment: You have a hard coded client id, this will only work if there is only ever a single browser with this page open. Check the broker logs that the client is not getting disconnected due to clashing clients.

Comment: The hard coded ID is not the issue as this is the only instance of the broker currently. The ID is hard coded for testing purposes of course. In the brooker logs the message is received to the topic, however, in the console it is not visible

Comment: The Client ID is now dynamic to ensure that this is not an issue. Still not receiving messages - excluding the one in  the onConnect function

Comment: What version of Paho are you using? 1.0.1 is latest and needs to use `Paho.MQTT` namespace

Comment: I am using Paho version 1.1.0 and Paho.MQTT is no longer used in this use case. I reverted back to version 1.0.1 and used 'Paho.MQTT.Client', however, the onmessage function wasn't even called at all in this case. Also no messages were being recieved when sent from a seperate client.